# objective c block to swift

Tags: swift, closures

I'm trying to invoke a method on an Objective-C class from Swift. It's for a pod called BoString, and here's the snippet

```
- (BOStringAttribute *(^)(NSParagraphStyle *))paragraphStyle
{
    return ^BOStringAttribute *(NSParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle) {
        return self.attribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, paragraphStyle);
    };
}
```

In Swift, I'm trying to invoke this method but the compiler complains if I try to pass any parameter in `paragraphstyle`

```
let str = BOStringMaker()
str.paragraphStyle() // OK
//*** error
str.paragraphStyle({(ps) -> BOStringAttribute in
   // logic here
})
```

In Objective-C, I used

```
BOStringMaker *make = [BOStringMaker alloc] init]
make.paragraphStyle(ps);
```

But i'm unable to do the same in Swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In swift you do the exact same thing. You get the `paragraphStyle` which is the block / function and then simply invoke it and pass in `ps` or whatever instance of `NSParagraphStyle` you currently hold as parameter:

```
formatText.paragraphStyle()(ps)
```

Comment: when i do that, i get error: "argument passed to call that takes no arguments (pointing to ps)